# Setup VPS (Bluehost) to deploy and update RoR apps (Heroku Style)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, bluehost

My goal is to setup my environment to be able to run $ **git push myapp master** on my local computer AND automatically deploy/update my RoR app on my VPS at Bluehost.

On my computer (Linux-Ubuntu) the RoR app is at:  **/var/www/myapp**

I followed this GREAT explained [tutorial](http://www.calzzani.com/blog/?p=92) and I have a plenty functional git installation on my VPS server at **~/git/repository/myapp**

Ideally, my deployed RoR app will be located on Bluehost at **~/rails_apps/myapp**

Bluehost automatically uses Pushion Passenger, and there is a symlink between **~/public_html/myapp** folder and the public side of the RoR app, located at **~/rails_apps/myapp/public**.

I am stuck with the post-receive git hook and I am not using Capistrano (should I?)

I have been reading many documents with similar goals, like [this one](http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/How-to-auto-deploy-Rails-apps-after-Git-push.html), or [this other one](http://ionrails.com/2009/07/15/installing-a-private-git-repository-on-your-shared-hosting-account-bluehost/), I even found [this gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/git-rails).

There are different ways to achieve same goal and I am still confused because I have not found a post-receive hook example that fits my need (and have not grasp the logic).

I have been on git guides specific section for [hooks](http://git-scm.com/docs/githooks.html) and it tells what you can do but not how to do it, which is great for everyone but a rookie.

Any help with the scenario and the goal? Will it be easier if I use Capistrano and/or git-rails gem? Other suggestions?

THANKS.

ADDITION:

Hi, I am using Capistano now but have not acheved the goal yet.

I have my app at /var/www/my_app on linux local machine.

The git repository remote --bare and --share is at user@myserver:/server/user/git/repository/my_app.

I want to deploy to /server/user/rails_apps/my_app.

At deploy.rb I have

set:application, "my_app".

set :respository, "user@myserver:/server/git/repository/my_app.

set:user, "my_user_name".

set: domain, "mysite.com".

set :scm, :git.

set_scm_command, "/server/user/bin/git".

set :scm_passphrase, "my_phrase".

set :deploy_to, "/server/user/rails_apps/my_app".

set :deploy_via, :remote_cache.

set :tmp_dir, "/server/user/tmp".

When I run it, tels me: fatal: No remote configured to list refs from.
Can you give me some guidance? Thanks.

Comment: Yes it will be easier to use Capistrano. Also check out Mina

Answer (score 1):

Yes, The standard way is Capistrano or Mina and provisioning a rails environment in a hosted directory. If you are hell bent on doing it the heroku way you can use Vagrant to provision your own heroku environment here: https://github.com/openruko/vagrant-openruko

Comment: I will check Capistrano and Mina and Vagrant. I just want to push my apps and be able to improve them after deploy basic version. I mentioned Heroku because I like to push with git, that I am bent with. Not sure what other advantages Vagrant will give. I will investigate. Thank you very much.

Comment: THe vagrant thing is to provision a heroku-clone environment, Vagrant recipies are good for provisioning boxes not really for deploying code.

Comment: Hi, again. Thanks for precision. I have been investigating Capistrano and I see is a deploy gem by itself and can be mixed with Git. What I really is to push my website with Git. First deployment will soon be improved with multilanguage version. Does Capistrano improves security or page response speed?

Comment: No not at all, it does nothing but get your code from your git repo or local copy to your webserver.

Comment: I am using Capistrano, but have not yet make it work. And even with that, I can see why people use it a lot. Thanks.

Comment: To deploy a large website its great, it allows you to manage a large # of servers, and run specific tasks on specific servers, you can deploy your app with one command to 20 servers, and then 5 different servers maybe clear cache or HUP your background workers.